# Unable to run the Powershell Script using SQL Server Job Agent

Tags: azure, powershell, sql-agent-job, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to execute my PowerShell script using the SQL Server Job Agent but unable to do so. I am able to execute the script successfully via PowerShell Prompt. Here in the Agent I am Operating System (CMDEXEC) and running as Service Account. Job is successfully executed but with following Error.

I am using the following command in command Window:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "& 'D:\Powershell\triggersinfo.ps1'" 

Message
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. ...because it does not exist.  At D:\Powershell\triggersinfo.ps1:4 char:98  + ... To-SecureString -Key (Get-Content D:\Triggers_Test\passwords\aes.key)  +                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Triggers_Test\passwords\aes.key:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundE      xception      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommandConvertTo-SecureString : Input string was not in a correct format.  At D:\Powershell\triggersinfo.ps1:4 char:69  + ... sword.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content D:\Triggers_Test ...  +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], FormatException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand     New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process argument because the value of argument   "password" is null. Change the value of argument "password" to a non-null value."  At D:\Powershell\triggersinfo.ps1:5 char:16  + ... redential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($use ...  +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommandConnect-AzAccount : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Credential' because it is null.  At D:\Powershell\triggersinfo.ps1:7 char:32  +  Connect-AzAccount -Credential $credential  +                                ~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], ParameterBindingValidationException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectA      zureRmAccountCommandGet-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger : Run Connect-AzAccount to login.  At D:\Powershell\triggersinfo.ps1:16 char:11  + $triggers=Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryNam ...  +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger], PSInvalidOperationException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.GetAzureDataFactoryTriggerCommandGet-AzStorageAccount : No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are   authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzAccount to login.  At D:\Powershell\triggersinfo.ps1:70 char:13  +  $account = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName 'DataLake-Gen2' - ...  +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzStorageAccount], ApplicationException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.GetAzureStorageAccountCommandNew-AzStorageAccountSASToken : Could not get the storage context.  Please pass in a storage context or set the current   storage context.  At D:\Powershell\triggersinfo.ps1:71 char:8  +  $sas= New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob  -ResourceType Serv ...  +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzStorageAccountSASToken], InvalidOperationException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.Cmdlet.NewAzure      StorageAccountSasTokenCommandInvoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make   sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the   signature.\nRequestId:c5b73384-401f-0061-7f95-b2677600...  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.
```

Any Idea why I a getting this error? If required I can also paste the whole PS Script here. Thanks

**Script Used:**

```
# Connect to Azure Account

 $username = "xyz@abc.com"
 $password = Get-Content D:\Triggers_Test\passwords\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content D:\Triggers_Test\passwords\aes.key)
 $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username,$password)

 Connect-AzAccount -Credential $credential

# Input Variables

 $dataFactoryName="dna-production-gen2"
 $resourceGroupName="DataLake-Gen2"

# get dataFactory triggers

$triggers=Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$datas=@()
foreach ($trigger in $triggers) {
    # get the trigger run history
    $today = Get-Date
    $yesterday = $today.AddDays(-1)
     $splat = @{ 
        ResourceGroupName       = $trigger.ResourceGroupName
        DataFactoryName         = $trigger.DataFactoryName
        TriggerName             = $trigger.Name
        TriggerRunStartedAfter  = $yesterday
        TriggerRunStartedBefore = $today
   }
    
   $historys =Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerRun @splat
   if($historys -ne $null){
     # create date
     foreach($history in $historys){
        $obj =[PsCustomObject]@{
            'TriggerRunTimestamp '     = $history.TriggerRunTimestamp
            'ResourceGroupName '   =$history.ResourceGroupName
            'DataFactoryName' =$history.DataFactoryName
            'TriggerName '  = $history.TriggerName
            'TriggerRunId'= $history.TriggerRunId
            'TriggerType'=$history.TriggerType
            'Status' =$history.Status

        }
        # add data to an array
        $datas += $obj
     }
   } 
   
  
 }

#  convert data to csv string

 $contents =(($datas | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join [Environment]::NewLine)

 # upload to Azure Data Lake Store Gen2

 #1. Create a sas token
 
  $accountName="dna2020gen2"
 
# $path = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"

 $YY = (Get-Date).year
 $MM = (Get-Date).month
 $DD = get-date –f dd
 
 $fileSystemName="dev"
 $filePath="triggers/YYYY=$YY/MM=$MM/DD=$DD/data.csv"
 $account = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName 'DataLake-Gen2' -Name $accountName
 $sas= New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob  -ResourceType Service,Container,Object `
      -Permission "racwdlup" -StartTime (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10) `
      -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2) -Context $account.Context
$baseUrl ="https://{0}.dfs.core.windows.net/{1}/{2}{3}" -f $accountName ,  $fileSystemName, $filePath, $sas

#2. Create file
$endpoint =$baseUrl +"&resource=file"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Content-Length" = 0} -UseBasicParsing

#3 append data
$endpoint =$baseUrl +"&action=append&position=0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Content-Length" = $contents.Length} -Body $contents -UseBasicParsing

#4 flush data
$endpoint =$baseUrl + ("&action=flush&position={0}" -f $contents.Length)
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $endpoint -UseBasicParsing

#Check the result (get data)

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $baseUrl -UseBasicParsing
```

Comment: Looks like an error in your script. A password is not read properly and auth fails. You should include your script it in the question. Try to reduce it to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that still produces this error.

Comment: @marsze: Updated the question with my scripts used, Password file and AES Key I have saved in the path provided in the script. I am getting this error as mentioned above. Also my password file and key works fine when I am running the script in PowerShell Prompt.